# To execute a function on the button click in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

[image]

In the above screenshot you will see a panel and there are three buttons namely hide, close and clear.
I want to perform a particular action on click of those buttons.
Can you please suggest me some approach to achieve it?

Actually the panel created below is nothing but a div container which I have appended to the body of the current webpage.
So I had tried with one approach to inject my own script in that particular webpage and perform a particular action on those button clicks.
But that didn't work for me.

Can you please suggest me some other approach?

This is my manifest file :-

```
    {
        "name": "Demo Extension",
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "manifest_version": 2,
        "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },


    "background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery-1.7.2.js","code.js"]
    },

    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["*://*/*"],
            "js": ["jquery-1.7.2.js","content.js"],
            "css": ["panel.css"],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ],

        "permissions": [
        "webRequest",
        "tabs",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*",
    ]
}
```

And my content.js file is as follows:

```
var data_div = $("<div class='panel'></div>");

data_div.css("position","fixed");
data_div.css("bottom","0px");
data_div.css("height","300px");
data_div.css("display","block");
data_div.css("width","100%");
data_div.css("overflow","scroll");
data_div.css("z-index","1004");
data_div.css("background-color","#C0C0C0");

$("body").append(data_div);

data_div.html("One big data set here");
```

Comment: Show us your manifest.json and script file

Comment: Why don't you just make your own buttons?

Comment: Please, provide more code related to the buttons handling, and describe what does not work exactly.

Comment: Hello stan there is no much code for the button.
Simply i have appended it to the dom and nothing else.

I wanted to know some approach to go about.
If i click on any of the above button then a particular function should be executed.
But i dont know where should i place that function, since content script executes only once after the page load completes it wont be useful and background script is also of not much use.............bcoz it wont be able to dom of the current page.
Plz suggest me some approach.

Comment: Yes, content script is executed once, but this is enouth for you to bind your click event handler to the buttons, as you usually do with jQuery, something like that: `$("#buttonid").click(function() { // handle click as appropriate here });`

Comment: So you mean i should write the function in content script only?
I had tried it, but it dint work for me.

Comment: What do you mean "didn't work"? Some errors (make sure to see console for the page where the content script is embedded)? Provide actual code of the content script.